# Map won't update to new location in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I'm doing the homework from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide. I can't get my map to show a new location. I know I'm using one deprecated method but I was having a problem using NSArray (the deprecated method is locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation). Any pointers would be appreciated.
Here's my code:
WhereamiViewController.h:

```
//  WhereamiViewController.h
//  Whereami
//
//  Created by Meghan on 2/28/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    IBOutlet UITextField *locationTitleField;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
}

- (void)findLocation;
- (void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc;

@end
```

WhereamiViewController.m:

```
//  WhereamiViewController.m
//  Whereami
//
//  Created by Meghan on 2/28/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WhereamiViewController.h"
#import "BNRMapPoint.h"

@interface WhereamiViewController ()

@end

@implementation WhereamiViewController

- (void)findLocation
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [locationTitleField setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];

    //Create an instance of BNRMapPoint with the current data
    BNRMapPoint *mp = [[BNRMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord
                                                       title:[locationTitleField text]];

    //Add it to the map view
    [worldView addAnnotation:mp];

    //Zoom the region to this location
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 250, 250);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    //Reset the UI
    [locationTitleField setText:@""];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [locationTitleField setHidden:NO];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        //Create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        //We want the most accuracy
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        //Tell our manager to start looking for location immediately
        [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);


    //How many seconds ago was this new location created?
    NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];

    //CLLocationManagers will return the last found location of the
    //device first, you don't want that data in this case.
    //If this location was made > 3 minutes ago, ignore it
    if (t < -180) {
        //This is cached data, you don't want it. Keep looking.
        return;
    }
    [self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    int degrees = (int)locationManager.heading.magneticHeading;
    NSLog(@"from delegate method: %i", degrees);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //Tell loc manager to stop sending messages
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //This method isn't implemented yet - but will be soon.
    [self findLocation];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

BNRMapPoint.h:

```
//  BNRMapPoint.h
//  Whereami
//
//  Created by Meghan on 3/4/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface BNRMapPoint : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{

}
//A new designated initializer for instances of BNRMapPoint
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t;

//This is a required property from MKAnnotation
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

//This is an optional property from MKAnnotation
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;

@end
```

BNRMapPoint.m:

```
//  BNRMapPoint.m
//  Whereami
//
//  Created by Meghan on 3/4/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BNRMapPoint.h"

@implementation BNRMapPoint

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _coordinate = c;
        [self setTitle:t];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.07, -89.32)
                              title:@"Hometown"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `initWithNibName` method, you're not calling `startUpdatingLocation` on the `locationManager` (you're only calling `startUpdatingHeading`).

(You are calling `startUpdatingLocation` in `findLocation` but that's only called from `textFieldShouldReturn`.)

The `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method is only called if you do `startUpdatingLocation`.

Also, make sure the `initWithNibName` method is actually getting called.
Depending on how this view controller is being created, you may need to move that startup code to `initWithCoder:` or `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can get updated location from this method in iOS

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{
location_updated = [locations lastObject];    
NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I made my location_updated an NSString type. now the following line: NSTimeInterval t = [[location_updated timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]; for that I get the error message: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'timestamp'

Comment: You can use NSTimer for continuous updating location search in Google how to use NSTimer

Comment: I also have the warning for the following line: [self foundLocation:location_updated]; Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'CLLocation *'....Just saw your answer. thanks!

Comment: I've used NSTimer and it still won't update to a new location. Not even once.